# Rule scenario manager in ilog

Tags: rule, ilog

I want to test a simple rule flow that has only one rule in it. i saw something called a Rule Scenario manager in Eclipse, is it related to testing ? Or can anyone help me in testing my ruleflow ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rule Configuration to test your rule or you can [create excel scenario](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmanager/v8r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wodm.dserver.rules.designer.test/topics/tsk_generate_excelfile.html) file for testing.